# ArcMap 10.3 Attribute Table Showing Wrong Information?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, select

I have some parcel data with addresses that I am trying to export as a selection. Every time I open the attribute table with a new selection of parcels, the information is incorrect after a certain point in the list.

Below is an example. I have my selection of Parcels [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI7c1.jpg) and the attribute table with the Owner information [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovvR2.jpg).  After the first row, all the information is the same after even though that information is incorrect. If there wasn't a selection, the information would be correct using the element information button.

[image: Parcel List Attribute Table]
[image: Selection of Parcels]

Comment: Some more information would be useful.  In what format is the source data? Have you verified that it isn't corrupt?

Comment: Is this a joined table?

Comment: Most likely overlapping polygons.